# /usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service:14 Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MDADM_CHECK_DURATION='"6 hours"'

Tags: rhel7

I am getting below messages on regular intervals in my /var/log/messages

```
Jun 23 09:33:10 sr001 systemd: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service:14] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MDADM_CHECK_DURATION='"6 hours"'
Jun 23 09:33:10 sr001 systemd: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.service:14] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MDADM_CHECK_DURATION='"6 hours"'
Jun 23 09:33:10 sr001 systemd: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service:14] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MDADM_CHECK_DURATION='"6 hours"'
Jun 23 09:33:11 sr001 systemd: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service:14] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MDADM_CHECK_DURATION='"6 hours"'
```

After doing some research I came to know this is some bug in RHEL 7

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1774354

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5191701

I want to understand what is this problem, how it will impact the server in terms of any system resource like cpu, ram etc. Is this something that we need to patch immediately.

```
[a_4@sr01 ~]$ uname -a
Linux sr01 3.10.0-1062.52.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 8 09:03:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```